# App works locally but not on IIS hosting server Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue on IIS 8.5 hosting server.

The app works fine on the developer machine and as well as on IIS on the same machine. 
But when it published to another server, it throws an error as below. App is build with framework 4.5 and installed the same on server as well.

Can anybody please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

> System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): d:\Teledokta Client
>   server\wwwroot\Views\Home\Index.cshtml(81): error CS0012: The type
>   'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You
>   must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType(String
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__3()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Controller controller) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Looks like you are missing a reference to `System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`

Answer (score 0):

Copy(replace if already exists) the aspnet_client folder of the project from the developer machine to the published folder of the hosting server, and then restart IIS.

Comment: Thanks Yasir, but Where it will be located?

Comment: In the published folder from where the project is hosted.